# Flutter: How to add a logo image on the left side of AppBar?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to add a logo image on the left side of my AppBar, as following: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qGIbb.png

This is my current code:

main.dart:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'home_page.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(title: "Chat App", home: new LoginPage());
  }
}
```

home_page.dart:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class LoginPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override 
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Smart ID',
      home: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          image: DecorationImage(
            image: AssetImage("assets/background.png"), fit: BoxFit.cover)),
        child: Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
          appBar: AppBar(
            elevation: 0,
            backgroundColor: Color(0xff05B068),
            centerTitle: true,
            title: Text('SMARTID', style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'Open Sans', fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
          ),
        ),
      )
    );
  }
}
```

How do I apply the logo image?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Do it like,

```
      appBar: AppBar(
        leading: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: Image.asset(
            "assets/images/appicon.png",
          ),
        ),
```

Output

[image]

Add your logo in assets folder like this,

[image]

Then open pubspec.yaml and add your logo,

[image]

At last, press get packages,

[image]

Answer (score 4):

There is a parameter called `leading` that takes a `widget` and places it on the left side of your `AppBar`.

Replace the `Icon` that i put with your logo:

```
AppBar(
          elevation: 0,
          backgroundColor: Color(0xff05B068),
          centerTitle: true,
          leading: Icon(Icons.arrow_forward_ios),
          title: Text('SMARTID', style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'Open Sans', fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
        ),
```